# Issue with instant run and Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-instant-run, instant-run

There seems to be an issue with instant run and Google Maps. Upon re-running an application to see changes, if the application is using Google Maps, a crash will occur. Here is part of the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused.xml from drawable resource ID 
           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
           ........
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused.xml from drawable resource ID 
          at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2640)
          .....
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/maps_btn_myl_pressed.png from drawable resource ID
```

The crash is occuring because of a `ResourcesNotFoundException`, which seems to be caused by files such as those listed in the above stacktrace.

Has anyone run into this issue, and if so, what is the fix?

Comment: it clearly saying the drawable is not found, plz check again for that

Comment: @W4R10CK These drawables are not part of my project.

Comment: `common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused.xml ` has the problem with id, check that issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and still no solution.

Comment: Same problem here so upvoted question... looks like pretty old, did you found solution ?

Answer (score 0):

try this in `gradle` file :

```
android {  
    defaultConfig {  
         vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
        }  
}
```

and use latest `buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'`